# Finding an explicit expression for the solution of an ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$
 $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
x & \mbox{for}
& x<1/2 \\ 1-x & \mbox{for} & x \geq 1/2 \end{array}\right.$$

Consider $x_0 \in (0,1)$. Find an explicit expression for the solution as a function of $t$ and $x_0$. For a fixed $x_0$ how smooth is this solution as a function of $t$?

My solution:

The general solution for this function is given by $x(t)=c_1e^t$ when $x(t)<1/2$ and $x(t)=1-c_2e^{-t}$ when $x(t)\geq 1/2$. I am not sure how to find the expression for the solution as a function of $t$ and $x_0$, so what I see is when $x_0 \geq 1/2$ then that would mean $c_2=1-x_0$, and if $x_0<1/2$, then that would mean $c_1=x_0$, but how can I relate that with $t$. Also, how when I fix $x_0$, I feel that one constant should be back to the general solution since when we have $x_0$ fixed we will have that the other constant is not defined to be a specific number.

I would appreciate any kind of help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two family of solutions exist on continuous intervals:

- $x(t) = C exp(t)$
- $x(t) = 1 + C exp(-t)$

If $x_0 \geq 1/2$ (assuming we start out problem at $t=0$, so the domain of our study is $t\geq 0$), then the latter applies. However, $x(0) = x_0 = 1 + C exp(0)$, therefore $C = x_0 - 1$. Now you have a solution $x(t)=1+\left(x_0-1\right)\exp{(-t)}$. Now the solution depends on the sign of $x_0-1$. But remember, $x_0 \geq 1/2$, so this solution would keep being over $1/2$ because always over 1.

If $x_0 < 1/2$, the first solution applies, $x(t) = C exp(t)$. In $x(0) = x_0 = C$ therefore $x(t) = x_0 exp(t)$. Now the question is "does $x(t)$ keep being inferior to 1/2 ?". If $x_0 < 0$, then it always works out because you have a strictly negative function, so always inferior to $1/2$. Now, if $0 < x_0 < 1/2$, we must find $t_1$ such that $x(t_1) = 1/2$ which is $t_1=ln \left(\frac{1}{2 x_0}\right)$. At that point, the model will change to a function of the form $1 + B exp(-t)$. It is continuous in $t_1$. $1+B exp\left(-ln \left(\frac{1}{2 x_0}\right)\right) = 1/2$ which gives you the value of $B$. Now $x(t)=1+Bexp(-t),t\geq t_1$ which is always above 1/2. So you have a piecewise solution in this case.

Comment: I think the solution for the second one is $x(t)=1-Ce^{-t}$

Comment: Also what about the function $x(t)=Ce^t$ in the first case??

Comment: And @Ahmed what do you mean by "what about the function"? If x_0 < 1/2, the ODE  has the form y' = y, so C exp(t) applies until it changes piecewise. If x_0 >= 1/2, the ODE is y' = 1-y, so 1+Cexp(-t) is correct too